# Adobe Air IOS Game not working in IOS8

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a game made in Adobe Air, specifically in Adobe Flash CS6 that was working in IOS7 normally but since i updated my phone to IOS8 the game is not working. It displays me just a black screen and nothing happens.

I wanna know if i need to do something in my as3 code to make the game work or if it is some bug from IOS8 that wasn't solved yet?

Tks

Comment: changing the code probably won't change anything, using a different Adobe AIR SDK should give better results.

Comment: Do you know someone specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must update your Adobe AIR SDK. Currently I recommend to use latest that include a lot of iOS8 fixes (15.0.0.302 at moment of this message)

1) Go to [Adobe AIR SDK at labs](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html)

2) Find there at the middle of page:

AIR SDK and Compiler for Mac OS XDownload AIR 15 SDK & Compiler for Mac OS X (TBZ2, 185 MB)
AIR SDK and Compiler for WindowsDownload AIR 15 SDK & Compiler for Windows (ZIP, 204 MB)

3) Download your version

4) Install it according to [Update AIR SDK in CS6 and newer](http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=4141)

5) Compile your IPA and test it.

P.S. Also go to [Released version of Adobe AIR SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) and compare this versions. If it newer - use Release. If Beta latest - use Beta. It's always stable.

Comment: Thanks. I´ll try and something i say.